# How to set an array inside a test when using Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, testing, rspec

I've been having an issue with testing a helper method in Rspec.  The issue is trying to find a way to iterate an array for the test.  Right now, the test block looks something like this:

```
describe "#helper_method" do
  it "interates the array" do
    int = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]]

    int.each do |x , y|
      expect(x).to do_something y
    end
  end
end
```

I'm getting a No method error: undefined method 'int'.  So the question is, how to make this work? Am I suppose to set the array outside of the block?

**Update 1**:
Some people are saying that this block works for them but it's probably because I should have included a bit more about the how it interacts with the helper as I think that's where the problem comes in. I edited the code below to give a bit more clarity.  I think the code above works because it's not actually involving the use of the helper method or pulling from the helper file?

```
describe "#helper_method" do
  it "interates the array" do
    int = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]]

    int.each do |x , y|
      expect(helper.helper_method(x)).to do_something y
    end
  end
end
```

I guess since it's expecting 'int' to come from somewhere inside the helper_method, it doesn't even look at what's right inside the current block?

**Update 2**:
Someone else asked if I can show them the helper_method. This is what's in the helper file that I'm testing, a simple case statement.

```
def helper_method(abc)
  case abc
    when :first
      "first"
    when :second
      "second"
    when :third
      "third"
    else
      "nothing"
  end  
end
```

Comment: It seems to work fine for me...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with what you have posted

Comment: @UriAgassi and bihaid Thanks, I made an edit that makes it more clear on why I'm getting the error.

Comment: @JCC can you share the code of your helper_method in the question.

Comment: @KirtiThorat I updated it to include the helper_method. Thanks.

Comment: @JCC Let's debug this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Answer (score 0):

I used a workaround which seems to be working but I would still like to know how to use a variable inside the test block above.  Here's how I got it to work.

```
describe "#helper_method" do
  it "interates the array" do
    [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]].each do |x , y|
    expect(helper.helper_method(x)).to do_something y
    end
  end
end
```

I just eliminated the variable setting.